# How to displaying list of games in horizontal way using boostrap?

Tags: html, css

I am new in Front end developer.. list of games showing in vertical way I also add a boostrap link and add some classes but still showing in vertical way like this:
[image]

```
<html>
<head><title>Game Catalog</title>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12">    
        <div class="col-3">
            <form id="game_load0" method="post" action="play.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="url" value="">
            </form>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="document.forms['game_load0'].submit();" title="Biker Lane" style="padding-right: 12px;">
            <img src="http://cdn.marketjs.net/games/biker-lane/localization/en/media/graphics/promo/icons/128x128.png" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <form id="game_load1" method="post" action="play.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="url" value="">
            </form>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="document.forms['game_load1'].submit();" title="Wild West Shootout" style="padding-right: 12px;">
            <img src="http://cdn.marketjs.net/games/wild-west-shootout/localization/en/media/graphics/promo/icons/128x128.png" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"/></a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want that list of games showing in column way using boostrap

Check this link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BveNJj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Demo image]Before using any **col class**, you need to add one class which is **row class**.

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
     //write col classes here
     </div>
</div>
```

**row class** is used for divide columns in one row.so by default it sets all content in a horizontal manner. For more details, please refer to this document.[Bootsrap grid structure](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Here is the exact code which you are looking for.

```
    <html>
<head><title>Game Catalog</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form id="game_load0" method="post" action="play.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="url" value="">
            </form>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="document.forms['game_load0'].submit();" title="Biker Lane" style="padding-right: 8px;">
            <img src="http://cdn.marketjs.net/games/biker-lane/localization/en/media/graphics/promo/icons/128x128.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form id="game_load1" method="post" action="play.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="url" value="">
            </form>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="document.forms['game_load1'].submit();" title="Wild West Shootout" style="padding-right: 8px;">
            <img src="http://cdn.marketjs.net/games/wild-west-shootout/localization/en/media/graphics/promo/icons/128x128.png" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

By using this code,2 images are coming in one row.you can change padding right as per your requirement.

Comment: Its working fine in my pc, I added the image of output with my code, please check it.Try to run this code in  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_bootstrap_editor.php this and preview the result in fullscreen.

Comment: This is online_bootstrap_editor.php screen not your laptop or desktop screen, You can try it in local server beacuse its not laptop and desktop screen

Comment: @Hayamkhan I tried this code in my local server too and in that, I am getting same result as it is in the attached image. I am using a laptop. Try this in your local server.

Comment: I also tried in my laptop on local server but there is no change on it

Comment: that's strange, you are using windows OS or other OS?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: @Hayamkhan I added my whole html file code.Just copy and paste it and then check in your screen.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Before you start defining you columns you need to add row as the parent element. Learn More here: [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#how-it-works)
Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Content Here
    </div>
</div>
```

I fixed your code here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLBbMV

Comment: `class="row"` take 100% width and then next `class="col-3"` is not divided

Comment: my code is updated please check it and also check this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BveNJj

Answer (score 0):

Did you at least checked the Twitter Bootstrap Doc? You should read this page before starting with Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      INSERT FORM OR DIV FROM GAME HERE
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      INSERT FORM OR DIV FROM GAME HERE
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      INSERT FORM OR DIV FROM GAME HERE
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You just need to replace 'INSERT FORM OR DIV FROM GAME HERE' by your form and img.